# augtool saving failed

Tags: linux, command-line, puppet

I am trying to set some parameter using `augtool` but getting strange error

```
Linux$ sudo augtool set /files/etc/abrt/abrt-action-save-package-data.conf/OpenGPGCheck no
error: Failed to execute command
saving failed (run 'print /augeas//error' for details)
```

I got following output from error:

```
Linux$ sudo augtool print /augeas//error
/augeas/files/etc/abrt/abrt-action-save-package-data.conf/error = "parse_failed"
/augeas/files/etc/abrt/abrt-action-save-package-data.conf/error/pos = "167"
/augeas/files/etc/abrt/abrt-action-save-package-data.conf/error/line = "6"
/augeas/files/etc/abrt/abrt-action-save-package-data.conf/error/char = "0"
/augeas/files/etc/abrt/abrt-action-save-package-data.conf/error/lens = "/usr/share/augeas/lenses/libreport.aug:20.14-.43:"
/augeas/files/etc/abrt/abrt-action-save-package-data.conf/error/message = "Iterated lens matched less than it should"
```

Same command working on other box. Not sure what is missing?

OS: CentOS7

```
augtool 1.1.0 <http://augeas.net/>
Copyright (C) 2007-2011 David Lutterkort
License LGPLv2+: GNU LGPL version 2.1 or later
                 <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl-2.1.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by David Lutterkort
```

## Update

```
augtool> print /augeas/files/etc/abrt/abrt-action-save-package-data.conf/error
/augeas/files/etc/abrt/abrt-action-save-package-data.conf/error = "parse_failed"
/augeas/files/etc/abrt/abrt-action-save-package-data.conf/error/pos = "167"
/augeas/files/etc/abrt/abrt-action-save-package-data.conf/error/line = "6"
/augeas/files/etc/abrt/abrt-action-save-package-data.conf/error/char = "0"
/augeas/files/etc/abrt/abrt-action-save-package-data.conf/error/lens = "/usr/share/augeas/lenses/libreport.aug:20.14-.43:"
/augeas/files/etc/abrt/abrt-action-save-package-data.conf/error/message = "Iterated lens matched less than it should"
augtool>
```

/etc/abrt/abrt-action-save-package-data.conf

```
# With this option set to "yes",
# only crashes in signed packages will be analyzed.
# the list of public keys used to check the signature is
# in the file gpg_keys
#
OpenGPGCheck = no

# Blacklisted packages
#
BlackList = nspluginwrapper, valgrind, strace, mono-core

# Process crashes in executables which do not belong to any package?
#
ProcessUnpackaged = yes

# Blacklisted executable paths (shell patterns)
#
BlackListedPaths = /usr/share/doc/*, */example*, /usr/bin/nspluginviewer, /usr/lib/xulrunner-*/plugin-container

# interpreters names
Interpreters = python2, python2.7, python, python3, python3.3, perl, perl5.16.2
```

Comment: Can you run `rpm -q libreport` and provide the contents of the conf file?

Comment: @m0dlx i have updated my question, Which `conf` file you referring?

Comment: /etc/abrt/abrt-action-save-package-data.conf, the one you're editing.

Comment: Updated my question with `/etc/abrt/abrt-action-save-package-data.conf` its standard file. all other system works but only this one has issue :(

Comment: I have update my question again and added `augtool` error, do you know what could be wrong there?

Comment: I can't see anything wrong, it parses fine for me with the lens you pasted in your edited question.  Try updating Augeas (EL7 has 1.4.0) and also try running dos2unix on the config file in case it has unusual line endings.